# "map.once is not a function error" trying to duplicate OpenLayers example

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am trying to duplicate this OpenLayers 6 example
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-map.html
It is to a javascript to download your OpenLayers 6 map

I am using different configuration and haven't been able to get it to work
http://australiamap.ca/export-map/

I get a "map.once is not a function error"

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code (i truncated some part for readability)

```js
window.onload = init;

function init(){
  const torontoCenterCoordinate = [-8850000, 5410000]
  const map = new ol.Map({
    view: new ol.View({
      center: torontoCenterCoordinate,
      zoom: 10
    }),
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    target: 'map'
  })
}

function init2(){
...
}

document.getElementById('export-png').addEventListener('click', function () {
  map.once('rendercomplete', function () {
    ...
  });
  map.renderSync();
});
```

You are trying to access variable `map` which is declare inside function `init` inside event listener of click. That's possible due to how scope work in JavaScript.
There is a coincidence that map actually resolve to a DOM element (in modern browser if you have an HTML element with id `map` then browser will save that element into variable `map` for you)

To fix your problem, you can either:

1. Move move to global scope so event listener can access it

```js
// outside of init
  const map = new ol.Map({
    view: new ol.View({
      center: torontoCenterCoordinate,
      zoom: 10
    }),
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    target: 'map'
  })
```

2. Move even listener inside `init`

```js
function init(){
  const torontoCenterCoordinate = [-8850000, 5410000]
  const map = new ol.Map({
    view: new ol.View({
      center: torontoCenterCoordinate,
      zoom: 10
    }),
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    target: 'map'
  })

  document.getElementById('export-png').addEventListener('click', function () {
    map.once('rendercomplete', function () {
      ...
    });
    map.renderSync();
  });
}
```

Comment: I have moved the code to global scope. It still isn't working. 
http://australiamap.ca/export-map/

Comment: @TedNye: i created a sanbox here no problem at all: https://0qpgb.csb.app/  sourcecode: https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-cache-0qpgb?file=/index.js

Comment: Can someone please identify why my script isn't working :)